# Function to define the @property for multiple attributes

Tags: python, lambda, decorator

I am trying to make a function that takes in a variable number of attributes from a class **instance** and redefines them as you would with @property, giving the attribute a getter and a setter.

I want to achieve this:

```
@property
def x(self):
    return self._x

@x.setter
def x(self, value):
    self._x = value

@property
def dx(self):
    return self._dx

@dx.setter
def dx(self, value):
    self._dx = value

@property
def dy(self):
    return self._dy

@dy.setter
def dy(self, value):
    self._dy = value
```

By doing something like this:

```
decorate_these_attributes(self.x, self.dx, self.dy)
```

Here what I have so far:

```
def decorate_these_attributes(self, *args):

    def attr_set(attr, val):
        attr = val

    for attr in args:
        attr_get = lambda: attr
        attr = property(attr_get, attr_set)
```

As of now, when I call the function, it doesn't do anything. Any ideas of what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Is your `decorate_these_attributes` defined inside your class?  Even then `attr = property(attr_get, attr_set)` wouldn't be assigned in the correct scope (at the `class` level).

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: Why not? Doing it the "normal" way is essentially writing the same function multiple times but returning different things. This way (in my opinion) is much cleaner.  @user2357112

Comment: @Robbie: The "normal" way is to not have any of these superfluous properties.

Comment: The "normal" way is debatable. I meant through using the decorator property. My fault for not being clear. @user2357112

Answer (score 2):

You could use class decorator or metaclass to do things like this:

```
def apply_property(cls):
    def make_getter(name):
        def getter(self):
            return getattr(self, name)
        return getter

    def make_setter(name):
        def setter(self, val):
            setattr(self, name, val)
        return setter

    for f in cls.fields:
        getter = make_getter('_' + f)
        setter = make_setter('_' + f)
        setattr(cls, f, property(getter, setter))
    return cls


@apply_property
class Point:
    fields = ['x', 'y', 'z']
```

I'm assuming that you have something more complex than your example in mind.
If that's not the case, I think you can just use plain attributes, no need for properties.
And in cases where you need different behavior for different properties, try searching "Python descriptor".

Comment: Yes this is totally correct for what I asked. The problem is my question was not what I meant. I meant that I want it so I can apply the decorator to multiple attributes of a class **instance**, not to multiple attributes of a class. Sorry for the confusion. I editted my question accordingly. @satoru